# 'npm start' command not working. No errors

Tags: reactjs, npm, command-line-interface

Until yesterday `npm run start` command worked for my react project. I am unsure if this could be the cause but I updated npm to 6.13.6 today.

There are no errors or vulnerabilities. This is affecting all my react projects. I tried a lot of solutions including removing and reinstalling the node packages. 
[image]

package.json includes the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

A debug log for a different project shows this: 
[image]

Comment: What happens when you use `npm run start`? There must be some sort of output in the console.

Comment: There is no output. It just goes to the next line right away for input after half a sec.

Comment: And what is the script that `npm start` is running? This is defined in package.json `scripts` section.

Comment: I am not sure why my question is downvoted. This is something I am genuinely trying to solve for the past several hours.

Comment: I'm not sure what this would do, but considering you upgraded npm and this started happening ... maybe try reverting the npm upgrade and running again?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your package.json file has the following code?

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems weird to me, have you tried removing node modules and reinstalling? 
you can also try enabling npm to debug log, https://github.com/npm/cli

Comment: I did try removing the node modules and reinstalling. I cloned a few of my old projects to test it out too. Other npm commands on the cli work, like npm audit/npm install. But this does not seem to work...

Comment: Working on trying to find the debug log...

Comment: This is an debug log generated for a different project with the ```npm start``` command.

Comment: @mothfly_dev it clearly says start command is missing. something wrong with your package json.